# Selecting content based on locale

Tags: django, django-models

Given I have description of say product x in multiple languages along with its price and availability dictated by region/locale, how do I go about telling django to render the most appropriate variant of the content based on region of request origin? Amazon would be a good example of what I am trying to achieve.

Is is best to store each variant in the database, and afterwards look at request header to serve the most appropriate content, or is there a best practise way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with  the same problem. The localeurl library seems to handle these cases, so you don't have to write the logic by yourself. I still haven't tested the library, but at first glance it seems to be exactly what we need. You can read more about it [here](http://django-localeurl.readthedocs.org/en/v2.0.1/usage.html)